# Jetpack Navigation: How to check if route exists already to avoid IllegalArgumentException on cannot be found in the navigation graph

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I am building the navigation graph dynamically and the code that calls navigate() finds that the route is not present yet. That may be a race condition or a bug but I still want to handle it gracefully instead of crashing with

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/XXX } cannot be found in the navigation graph NavGraph(0x0) startDestination={Destination(0x78d845ec) route=home}
```

I am not able to find any `navController.exists(route)` option that I can use before calling `.navigate()`.

```
Column(modifier = Modifier
       .fillMaxSize()   
       .align(Alignment.CenterStart)
       .clickable {     
           navController.navigate(item.key) 
       }) { ...  }
```

Is catching exception is the only option to handle it gracefully?

There are suggestions such as checking `navController.currentBackStackEntry?.destination?.id` but that need not be the intended destination.

Comment: "That may be a race condition or a bug" - it is always a bug on your side. You should just fix the bug.

Comment: You can simply avoid the crash by adding a try/catch block. But look, your users will get a very weird experience. They click on a Button, then nothing happens. So you should verify the items you generated to remove all items that don't appear on your navigation graph. In case you don't know which to remove, you should add a way to notify your user when you cannot navigate to the item's destination.